# Remove price increase on configurable swatches

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, price, swatches

I am having trouble removing the price increase from configurable swatches. As you can see in the image it says +$10.00 - this bit is what i am trying to remove. **The price should still change but the area in red should not be shown.**

[image: Example of price increase]

The indigo colored area is: `<dt class="swatch-attr">`

The red colored ares is: `<span id="select_label_wd_sssg">`

The swatch buttons are wrapped in: `<span class="swatch-label">`

I have unsuccessfully tried to remove this using this bit of code
    
    //

```
    jQuery("swatch-label").click(function(){
        checkswatches();
    });
});

function checkswatches(){
  jQuery("#select_label_wd_sssg").select(function(){
    var optiontext = jQuery(this).text();
    var addsignpos = optiontext.indexOf('+');
    var subtractsignpos = optiontext.indexOf('-');
    if(addsignpos>0){
        var result = optiontext.substring(0,addsignpos-1);
        jQuery(this).html(result);
    }

    if(subtractsignpos>0){
        var result = optiontext.substring(0,subtractsignpos-1);
        jQuery(this).html(result);
    }
  });
}
// ]]>
```

*Can't get code to format correctly*

I have put the code above inside of

`app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml`

and `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable/swatches.phtml` with no luck.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you want to have parent product price for all config child products? In another word, price shouldn't change no matter what customer chooses from config option.

Comment: No the price should change. It should not however show the price increase/decrease from the parent (default) product. In the example above the +$10.00 should not show. The code shows this action.

Answer (score 1):

In skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/configurableswatches/swatches-product.js find this:

```
/**
     * Return text that should be displayed in attribute label for a certain option
     *
     * @param {object} option
     * return {string}
     */
    getOptionLabel: function(option) {
        return this.productConfig.getOptionLabel(option, option.price);
    },
```

and change it to this:

```
/**
     * Return text that should be displayed in attribute label for a certain option
     *
     * @param {object} option
     * return {string}
     */
    getOptionLabel: function(option) {
        return this.productConfig.getOptionLabel(option);
    },
```

Comment: I'm using CE 1.9.3.x and this didn't work for me. Still seeing the price adjustment after cache flush and reindex. Applied to RWD & my theme

Comment: It's weird cause I just did it yesterday on a 1.9.3.3 community edition and it worked both on local and prod

Comment: I checked my files and caching but still don't see the desired change. I updated the file in RWD and copied it to my theme as well. Is there anywhere else that I should check?

Comment: Maybe it depends on your theme? Try and switch to rwd and see if the fix works there so you can rule out any theme related issues

Comment: Coming back to this - the .js file was being loaded from a different area in my theme. Once I found this, the change worked. Use your "view source" and search for the .js file being used - it may be different than the path given in this answer, but the modification definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    Product.ConfigurableSwatches.prototype.getOptionLabel = function(option){
       return option.label;
    };
});
```

Into any script to overwrite default swatches-product.js behaviour